# How to prevent backspace with Nodejs readline (readable stdin)

Tags: node.js, stdin, tty

I wrote a [simple programe](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js) to manage command line user interface.

To do so, I use Nodejs Readline API to read the `process.stdin` Stream.

My problem is that if a user start typing, then press backspace, the complete line is deleted and fallback to default prompt style; until the user press `enter`. It looks like that:

```
What's your phone number?:
# User start typing
What's your phone number?: 123
# User press backspace
> 12
```

(you could test it running the example [the repo examples folder](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/tree/master/examples))

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? (or to somehow hide it)